# Increment Workflow Variables

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-variable

I've done quite a bit of research, but unable to find a solution or tutorial to help me with this problem. I am looking for an out-of-box solution using SharePoint Designer 2010.

I have a document library:
Folder 1
  Sub-folder A
    Sub-folder 1a

In 1a, when a user uploads three documents that end with "_one", "_two", and "_three", I would like to send an email to user(s).

My potential solutions that I have tried unsuccessfully include: incrementing a workflow variable each time one of these documents is added by 1. However, workflow variables are reset each time. I also tried creating a column "Value", and have this increment by +1. However, I am unable to figure out how to do this.

Please let me know if I can offer any additional details. I would also appreciate references and resources to bolster my knowledge so I don't have to ask such basic questions.

Answer (score 0):

The second option (`creating a new column to hold the incremental value`) is appropriate to your requirements but you will need to use the below actions:

- **Do Calculation** the new column value and add 1 then add this value to variable.

  - Calculate Your new column name plus 1 (Output to Variable: calc )
- **Update list item**, to update the field on the current list item with this variable

  [image]

Comment: Problem with this approach is how do I know when all three of those documents are uploaded. These documents that I am verifying have specific strings that they end with in their filename. Before the plan was to get to 3, and knowing I am there. But with use of ID column, this isn't possible because if you add and delete three random documents, our ID has reached 3.

Comment: Is it possible to get the maximum value of a column? So this would work similar to the approach you outlined, but it would be with a column I create, and not ID. This way I can control its increment.